# В таблице гугл отобрать фильтром строки по нескольким критериям и вывести результат в одну строку

Tags: google-spreadsheet, таблицы

Братцы, выручайте! Выходной день потратил на поиск решения - не осилил :(
Как одной формулой отобрать фильтром строки по нескольким критериям и вывести результат в одну строку? Вывести в одну строку - не проблема, проблема именно в отборе фильтром сразу по нескольким заданным критериям, без перебора по-отдельности. Пробовал формулы массива, LAMBDA, другие варианты - не идёт [Таблица с примером тут](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11icrz71ybT9jLSkCVwWGthzZsP2N7hLZfT4Ij91H2GU/edit?usp=sharing)
Уверен, красивое решение задачи существует

Comment: `COUNTIF(A20:A21;A5:A12)` - попробуйте в фильтр в качестве условия

Comment: можете подробнее рассказать про условия?

Comment: Есть массив, в столбце А содержатся уникальные значения. Нужно выбрать строки из массива, которые в столбце А содержат заданные значения. Заданных значений может быть несколько, до 30-ти, перебирать каждое - не вариант

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё одно решение - выбираются строки, содержащие заданные в столбце А значения:
=torow(CHOOSEROWS(B5:G13;ArrayFormula(ЕСЛИОШИБКА(ПОИСКПОЗ(filter(A21:A27;A21:A27<>"");A5:A13;0))));1)

Answer (score 0):

Аноним предоставил красивое решение:
=torow(ТРАНСП(choosecols(ТРАНСП(B5:G13);{СМЕЩ(A21;0;0;СЧЁТЗ(A21:A29);1)}));ИСТИНА)
Это жесть, парни, я вчера тоже с choosecols упражнялся и так и сяк, но никак.
Чей это ответ? Большое спасибо!